# MVC 4 Updating a view with a controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC. I want to be able to change a button/divs/textboxes text when a view's button is clicked.  I found a tutorial online that showed me the following but when I click the button I'm getting redirected to another page.  That page shows the text instead. I haven't touched the default Global.aspx

View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ExamineTextBox", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("textBox1")
    <input type="submit" value="Button" />
    <span id="result" />
}
```

Controller

```
public string ExamineTextBox(string textBox1)
{
    if (textBox1 != "Initial Data")
    {
        return "This text is MVC different from before!";
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page.

If you are using the default bundles (take a look at `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` - you will see a `jqueryval` bundle defined which combines and minifies all `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*` and `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"` files):

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

and if not using bundles you could include only this script individually:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

It is this script that is required for `Ajax.*` helpers to work. As it name indicates it unobtrusively AJAXifies them. It depends on jQuery so make sure you have that one included as well.

Side note: In ASP.NET controller actions should return ActionResults, not strings:

```
public ActionResult ExamineTextBox(string textBox1)
{
    if (textBox1 != "Initial Data")
    {
        return Content("This text is MVC different from before!");
    }
    return Content(String.Empty);
}
```

Here's how your full view code might look:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    </head>
    <body>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("ExamineTextBox", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
        {
            @Html.TextBox("textBox1", "Initial Data")
            <input type="submit" value="Button" />
            <span id="result" />
        }
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    </body>
</html>
```

and the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ExamineTextBox(string textBox1)
    {
        if (textBox1 != "Initial Data")
        {
            return Content("This text is MVC different from before!");
        }
        return Content(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just copied that exact code and couldn't get it to work.  The one difference is I used <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script> instead of the bundles.  Am I missing another script?

Comment: No, you are not missing another script. Make sure those scripts exist at the specified location. Also you need to invert the order => include `jquery` first. As I already specified in my answer `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` depends on `jquery` so if you haven't included jquery before it won't work.

Comment: The @Script renders are all removed.  I put the jquery above the jquery.unobstrusive and they are at the specified location.  When I click the button it does nothing.  Before when the .unobstrusive was before the jquery it loaded a page with the /Home/ExamineTextBox url with no text on the page

Comment: Did you change the text in the textbox? Because in your controller action you are checking whether the value differs from the initial value and return nothing otherwise.

Comment: Hahaha I'm a frustrated fool.  Thank you very much.